# Apply Android Gradle plugin using new syntax

Tags: android, gradle, plugins, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

How can I apply Android plugin using new Gradle plugin syntax:

```
plugins {
    id "..." version "..."
}
```

Instead of:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

Comment: The plugins block will be properly supported in android gradle plugin 4.2. Until then, use the pluginManagement workaround below. Source:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64551265

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem and found the solution [here](https://medium.com/@StefMa/its-time-to-ditch-the-buildscript-block-a1ab12e0d9ce). The problem results from the fact that Google for whatever reasons decided to put the application plugin not into Gradle's repository of community plugins.

In `build.gradle` remove the buildscript block completely and just add

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '3.4.0'
}
```

In `settings.gradle` add

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id == "com.android.application") {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this working on the latest version? 
I'm getting this error: `Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.BaseExtension'.`

Comment: All good, but better to use per-namespace check: `requested.id.namespace == "com.android"`

Comment: @Treviño is right, please edit your answer to prevent exceptions like: `Plugin [id: 'com.android.library'] was not found in any of the following sources`. If you check the namespace with `requested.id.namespace == "com.android"` everything works fine

Comment: I'm guessing this isn't a problem anymore? [Docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin) indicate that the plugin should be added to the `plugins{ }` block.

Answer (score -2):

You should place it right after build script block in your app level gradle file.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
   id "me.tatarka.retrolambda" version "3.7.0"
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
     jcenter()
     maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: This is not answering the question

Answer (score -3):

This should do it.

```
plugins {
  id "com.android.application" version "<desired version>"
}
```

See the DSL at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block

The id is what you'd previously "apply".

Comment: `Error:(3, 0) Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '2.3.0'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Gradle Central Plugin Repository (no 'com.android.application' plugin available - see https://plugins.gradle.org for available plugins)`

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work. I get `Error:(10, 0) Plugin 'com.android.application' is already on the script classpath. Plugins on the script classpath cannot be applied in the plugins {} block. Add  "apply plugin: 'com.android.application'" to the body of the script to use the plugin.`

Comment: This is incorrect. The plugin ID is not necessarily the same you'd use with `apply plugin`. Also, as others commented, AFAIK the Android gradle plugin can't yet be applied with the "new" gradle plugin DSL

Comment: This does work now. See [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-plugin).