# Cause: androidx.navigation.safeargs can only be used with an androidx project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation, android-safe-args

I am facing issue with navigation component called `safeargs`.

I have used `classpath 'androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.0.0'` in build gradle.

While applying plugin `androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin` in `app/build.gradle`, I am getting following error:

> Cause: androidx.navigation.safeargs can only be used with an androidx
>   project

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.navigationexample"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `app/build.gradle`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake added `build.gradle` file. Please check it.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As per the [Migrate to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate), your `gradle.properties` file must contain the following lines:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

That first line, `android.useAndroidX=true`, is what the `androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin` uses to ensure you are using an AndroidX project (it is also used by other tools in Android Studio to generate the right classes, such as when you are using any of the templates).

Comment: I already have this in my `gradle.properties` and I am still facing the issue. Any clues?

Answer (score 32):

One other thing to remember is that `apply plugin:"androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` shouldn't be the top most `apply` on build.gradle.

This doesn't work:

```
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

This works:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

Answer (score 11):

The only thing that worked for me was.

In top of build.gradle file for the project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.4.2"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

In the same file under plugins add:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.2' apply false
}
```

In the build.gradle file for Module, under plugins add:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Put `classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.0"` to your
**project** build.gradle in `buildscript.dependencies` section.

But put `apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'` to your **app** build.gradle.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a bug. If your problem continues, you can try it like this. It worked for me too.

```
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

Comment: This errors if you just replace 'apply plugin:' with 'id'.  Remember now everyone knows what you are talking about.  This needs to be wrapped in 'plugins {}' See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55753364/346309

Answer (score 2):

**Solution**

Create `gradle.properties` file inside app (if not exist already) folder and add the content of this example file into it. Sync your project and it worked for me.

[Example gradle.properties File](https://github.com/lmj0011/jetpack-release-tracker/blob/master/gradle.properties.example)

Chill Pill :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have added the below lines in Gradle properties file then its okay

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Please add this line to your project-level build.gradle

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"
```

or current updated version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full plugins block:

plugins {
id 'kotlin-kapt'
id 'com.android.application'
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
**id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'**
}

make sure  id **'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'** is at the last down position...that's how I did

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple modules, you have to put the `classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:2.3.5"` into `build.graddle` in the root of project, not the one in the module. Then you can use `id "androidx.navigation.safeargs"` in the module.

Comment: I have done all of these you said but problem still exist